# Фиксирование изменений словаря для применения их к другому

Tags: javascript

Есть объект `A`, он содержит произвольный многоуровневый словарь `B`, при изменении любого элемента в котором должны производиться такие же изменения в идентичном словаре `C`.
Объект `A` и словарь в нём можно оформить как угодно, словарь `С` и словарь `B` не должны иметь ссылки на одинаковые объекты.
Словари сходятся к примитивным типам (число, строка и т.д.).
Желательно чтоб словарь `B` вёл себя как обычный словарь.

Comment: Если конкретнее, то я хочу сделать кеширование объекта `Memory` в игре `Screeps`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @nörbörnën я уже попробовал решить эту задачу с помощью `Proxy`, но мне нужно получить полный путь к изменяемому значению, и я никак не пойму как это сделать

Comment: можно решить в лоб: каждый объект делать Proxy и хранить пары в WeakMap

Comment: @nörbörnën а нет другой альтернативы без использования `Proxy` на каждом объекте? Просто в контексте данной задачи нужно создавать всё по новой каждые несколько минут, а в самом словаре могут быть сотни объектов

Comment: я не знаю альтернатив. а твоя ситуация - копеечная по расходам

Comment: вот тут, на первый взгляд, нормальный пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/41300128/4496422, хотя deleteProperty забыт. person - твой C, proxy - твой B.

Comment: Благодарю, это то что нужно

Comment: @nörbörnën хотя там совсем ничего не написано про данную задачу, но использование рекурсии таким образом, как там, подтолкнуло меня к решению задачи

Answer (score 1):

Увидев в одном из примеров кода, как можно использовать рекурсию с `Proxy`, написал свой велосипед:

```
var reqQuerry = []

let memHandler = {
  get (target, key) {
    reqQuerry.push(key)
    if (typeof target[key] === 'object' && target[key] !== null) {
      return new Proxy(target[key], memHandler)
    } else {
      return target[key];
    }
  },
  set (target, key, value) {
    if (target[key] !== value) {
      console.log('setting Memory');
      target[key] = value
      let Mem = Memory
      for (let i = 0; i < reqQuerry.length; i++) {
        Mem = Mem[reqQuerry[i]]
      }
      Mem[key] = value
    }
    return true
  },
  deleteProperty (target, key) {
    if (key in target) {
      delete target[key]
      let Mem = Memory
      for (let i = 0; i < reqQuerry.length; i++) {
        Mem = Mem[reqQuerry[i]]
      }
      delete Mem[key]
      return true
    }
    console.log('property not found at Memory.' + reqQuerry.join('.') + '.' + key + '!');
    return false
  }
}

var _memory = new Proxy({_mem : null}, {
  update (target) {
    if (target._mem == null) {
      console.log('refreshing Memory');
      target._mem = Object.assign({}, Memory)
    }
    reqQuerry = []
  },
  get (target, key) {
    this.update(target)
    return memHandler.get(target._mem, key)
  },
  set (target, key, value) {
    this.update(target)
    return memHandler.set(target._mem, key, value)
  },
  deleteProperty (target, key) {
    this.update(target)
    return memHandler.deleteProperty(target._mem, key)
  }
})

module.exports = _memory;
```

Писал скрипт для игры `Screeps`, так что синтаксис соответствующий.
`A => _memory` `B => _mem` `C => Memory`